# Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Tags: react-native

I've tried looking for a way to solve this error. It's occurring to me while I try to install my app with `react-native run-android`.

Already took a look at the solutions from [this thread](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3437), but my project isn't named `native`, `./gradlew clean` from the android folder didn't work, and I tried deleting the `.gradle` folder. I've also tried my own simple solutions that sometimes work for whatever reason - uninstalling the app from my phone before re-running `react-native run-android` and reopening VSCode.

This error started occurring after I installed react-native-unimodules, following the [android instructions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-unimodules). A potential problem I see from this is just that react-native-unimodules is supposed to be for Expo and I'm doing things with React Native CLI, but from what I understood, this is allowed.

My react-native version is 0.61.5, react-native-cli is 2.0.1.

Edit:
[build.gradle](https://drive.google.com/file/d/195ihl0HTpYHHLbm8rXH675i2bB0mTa3M/view?usp=sharing) file, as requested.
Also, I don't know if it's relevant, but since it was part of one of the suggested answers, I'll mention this as well: in the gradle.properties file, 
`android.useAndroidX=true` and `android.enableJetifier=true` were already present.

Comment: attach your build gadle file into this

Comment: have you configure $JAVA_HOME ?

Comment: [`build.gradle`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/195ihl0HTpYHHLbm8rXH675i2bB0mTa3M/view?usp=sharing), from the android folder.

I haven't configured any $JAVA_HOME file, where is it located and how do I configure it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common case, but what ive figured out during my app building, these steps always helped.

First you need to add below lines in gradle.properties file

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Then after that you need to install, jetfier via either `yarn` or `npm` like :

```
npm i jetifier // first this then the below

npx jetify
```

After that again re-bundle your code and then run, hope it helps. Feel free for doubts